# About Hirzebruch Surface and its blow up

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The Hirzebruch surface $\sum n$, $n>0$, blown up at a point on the special curve $D$ is isomorphic to $\sum n+1$ blown up at a point not on the special curve. Special curve is the only weil divisor on $\sum n$ whose self intersection number is negative. How to prove it? Which thesis does the proposition appear on? $\sum n$ is viewed as a $2$-dimension integral projective scheme over $C$.

Comment: This is equivalent to show that Nagata transform send $\Sigma_n$ to $\Sigma_{n+1}$. Since these transform sends ruled surfaces to ruled surfaces over $\mathbb P^1$ you just need to check that the self intersection of the exceptionnal divisor is $-n$.

Comment: @N.H. Can you explain more about Nagata transform? I haven't learnt it before. Could you give me some reference about the proposition or Nagata transform? Thank you so much.

Comment: This is the transformation which you describe. Toric description : the fan of $\Sigma_n$ is generated by the vectors $e_1, e_2, -e_2$ and $-e_1 + ne_2$. Blowing-up a point on the exceptional fiber is putting an edge between $-e_1 + ne_2$ and $e_2$, and blowing down is the same as deleting the edge $-e_1 + ne_2$. If you don't know toric geometry the best is probably to read a bit about surfaces, a book where Nagata transform, blow-up and $(-1)$ curves are discuted. I don't know such reference but probably the notes by Reid Milne might be nice : https://arxiv.org/pdf/alg-geom/9602006.pdf

Comment: @N.H. I have figured it out. When blowing up the point on the special curve, the fiber through the point will become a -1 curve. Then blow down the -1 curve. Thank you so much!

Comment: Sure but I didn't do much, you found by yourself :)